# Apply CSS class to element "A" when element "B" has a cetain class

Tags: jquery, css

I have two completely separate DIV elements on a page. I want div A to have a class of "red" only when div B has the class "flagged". Div B is an AJAX-enabled "flagging" button. Basically, I want div A to become red when one of the Div B items has been clicked/flagged.

I already have the class changing on div B when it is clicked/flagged, so now I just need the code (jquery?) that will apply a new class to the div A when that div B item has been flagged and thus has the class "flagged" associated with it.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide code or jsfiddle example

Comment: There is no "classchanged" event, so you'll just have to add the class to "A" whenever the class is added to "B", should be trivial?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQuery example that should do what you want. This example assumes you have a `<div id="divA">` and `<div id="divB">`.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#divB').click(function() {
        $('#divA').addClass('myRedClass');
    });
});
```

The first line ensures the document loaded before the jQuery inside is executed. The second line targets the "click" event of #divB. The third line actually adds the class to #divA. So - when #divB is clicked, add the class to #divA.

Comment: .. and yes, the second comment on the OP question by adeneo is correct, hence this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) and pass in a condition.  Since you didn't post your code I just made it really general

```
$('div.b').click(function(){ // <-- your click function 
   // changing of your div.b class
   $('div.a').toggleClass('red',$(this).hasClass('flagged');
   // now if div.b has class flagged - div.a will have class red also.. and vice/versa
});
```